# How do I reproduce Kou (2002) double exponential model in python?

Tags: python, quantitative-finance

I am trying to implement the Kou double exponential model for option pricing in Python, but I cannot find where I go wrong. I have defined the `Hh` function both recursively, and via approximation with the confluent hypergeometric function, both produce similar results. Can someone help me find the mistake, and provide intermediate results for the 9.14732 in Kou's original paper? See code below

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.special import hyp1f1, gamma, comb, factorial

def Hh(n,x):
    if n<-1: return 0
    elif n==-1:
        return np.exp(-x**2/2)
    elif n==0:
        return np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*norm.cdf(-x)
    else:
        return (Hh(n-2,x)-x*Hh(n-1,x))/n


def Hh1(n,x):
    p1 = 2**(-n/2)*np.sqrt(np.pi)*np.exp(-x**2/2)
    p2 = hyp1f1(n/2+1/2,1/2,x**2/2)/(np.sqrt(2)*gamma(1+n/2))
    p3 = x*hyp1f1(n/2+1,3/2,x**2/2)/gamma(1/2+n/2)
    return p1*(p2-p3)

def P(n,k,eta1,eta2,p):
    if n==k:
        return p**n
    else:
        P = 0
        for i in range(k,n):
            P += comb(n-k-1,i-k)*comb(n,i)*(eta1/(eta1+eta2))**(i-k)*(eta2/(eta1+eta2))**(n-i)*p**i*(1-p)**(n-i)
        return P

def Q(n,k,eta1,eta2,p):
    if n==k:
        return (1-p)**n
    else:
        Q = 0
        for i in range(k,n):
            Q += comb(n-k-1,i-k)*comb(n,i)*(eta1/(eta1+eta2))**(n-i)*(eta2/(eta1+eta2))**(i-k)*p**(n-i)*(1-p)**i
        return Q

def I(n,c,alpha,beta,delta):
    I = 0
    if beta>0 and alpha!=0:
        for i in range(n+1):
            I += (beta/alpha)**(n-i) * Hh1(i,beta*c-delta) + (beta/alpha)**(n+1) * (np.sqrt(2*np.pi)/beta) * np.exp(alpha*delta/beta+alpha**2/(2*beta**2)) * norm.cdf(-beta*c+delta+alpha/beta)
        
    elif beta<0 and alpha<0:
        for i in range(n+1):
            I += (beta/alpha)**(n-i) * Hh1(i,beta*c-delta) - (beta/alpha)**(n+1) * (np.sqrt(2*np.pi)/beta) * np.exp(alpha*delta/beta+alpha**2/(2*beta**2)) * norm.cdf(beta*c-delta-alpha/beta)
    else: 
        I = 0
    return I

def U(mu,sigma,lambd,p,eta1,eta2,a,T, bound=13):

    def Pi(n):
        return np.exp(-lambd*T)*(lambd*T)**n/factorial(n)
    
    exp1 = np.exp((sigma*eta1)**2*T/2) / (sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi*T))
    exp2 = np.exp((sigma*eta2)**2*T/2) / (sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi*T))

    sum1 = 0
    sum2 = 0
    for n in range(1,bound):
        sumP = 0
        sumQ = 0
        for k in range(1,n+1):
            sumP += P(n,k,eta1,eta2,p) * (sigma*np.sqrt(T)*eta1)**k * I(k-1,a-mu*T,-eta1,-1/(sigma*np.sqrt(T)),-sigma*eta1*np.sqrt(T))
            sumQ += Q(n,k,eta1,eta2,p) * (sigma*np.sqrt(T)*eta2)**k * I(k-1,a-mu*T,eta2,1/(sigma*np.sqrt(T)),-sigma*eta2*np.sqrt(T))
        sum1 += Pi(n)*sumP
        sum2 += Pi(n)*sumQ

    return exp1*sum1 + exp2*sum2 + Pi(0)*norm.cdf(-(a-mu*T)/(sigma*np.sqrt(T)))

def Kou(r,sigma,lam,p,eta1,eta2,S0,K,T):
    zeta = (p*eta1)/(eta1-1)+((1-p)*eta2)/(eta2+1)-1
    lam2 = lam * (zeta+1)
    eta12 = eta1 - 1
    eta22 = eta2 + 1
    p2 = (p/(1+zeta))*(eta1/(eta1-1))
    omega1 = r+sigma**2/2-lam*zeta
    omega2 = r-sigma**2/2-lam*zeta
    return S0*U(omega1,sigma,lam2,p2,eta12,eta22,np.log(K/S0),T) - np.exp(-r*T)*K*U(omega2,sigma,lam,p,eta1,eta2,np.log(K/S0),T)


S0=100
sigma=0.16
r=0.05
lam=1
n1=10
n2=5
tau=0.5
K=98
q=0.4
```

Comment: How could we guess the mistake if we have no reference output from the paper?

Comment: See footnote 9, with initial parameters also at the end of my code.